# how to create DB in visual studio 2010 ultimate

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

i am using visual studio 2010 ultimate.i have problem to using sql server in VS 2010.i find server explorer in this but i do not know how to create a new connection and what are its authentications.how to create a new data base in server explorer.what is the name of server and authentication for it.please explain?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a database from Server Explorer

- From the View menu, choose Server Explorer.
- In Server Explorer right-click Data Connections and choose Add
  Connection.
- If this is the first connection you make, the Choose Data Source
  dialog box appears. Under Data Source choose the kind of data source
  to which you are connecting, and then under Data Provider choose the
  appropriate provider for the application you are working with.
  Finally click Continue.
- In the Add Connection dialog box, enter the requested
  information.

  ```
   This information is different for each provider. For more
   help on this tab, click the Help icon at the top of the dialog box or
   press F1 with the dialog box selected.
  ```
- Choose the Advanced button to open a list of settings you can change
  for the selected provider.
- Choose Test Connection to check the connection without closing the
  dialog box. This way you can make adjustments to the settings if the
  connection does not succeed.
- Click OK.

Your connection appears in Server Explorer under the Data Connections node.